# Updating a Trello board label text with Trello.NET

Tags: c#, api, trello, trello.net

Using `board.LabelNames = labels` with Trello.NET, doesn't update the label texts on the board.

Even when followed by calling

```
trello.Boards.Update(board);
```

Any other way to do this? Or is this a missing feature in Trello.NET?

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented. <strike>I can't find it in the Trello API docs either (https://trello.com/docs/).</strike>

**Edit:** It's available in the Trello API now, but not implemented in Trello.NET. Follow progress [here](https://github.com/dillenmeister/Trello.NET/issues/23).

Regarding `Boards.Update` not updating all properties of `Board`: `Boards.Update` does not take a `Board` as a parameter, but an `IUpdatableBoard`. Only the properties of that interface will be updated. This goes for all Update methods in Trello.NET.